# how to create a new entity with parent key or string ID inside a MapReduce job?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, app-engine-ndb

I would like to add a `parent key` at some entities using MapReduce. If I understand correctly, I can not because a key is not editable. But if I try to create a new one for each entity with this code:

```py
a = Analisi(parent=new.key,
            computo=cme.key,
            voce=new.key)
a.put()
```

I get this error: `Analisi() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parent'`. 
Same thing if I try to assign a string ID. What did I miss?

update:

```py
class Analisi(ndb.Model):
    computo = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=ComputoMetrico)
    voce = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=VoceComputo)
```

If I switch to Expando, I don't get the error below but Mapreduce create a property named 'parent'. Seems that MapReduce can't manage ndb key class instances.
I use `mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreKeyInputReader` and convert to ndb with `from_old_key()` method in the handler: always work except when it must create new ndb keys.

Comment: Looks ok.  What does the class for Analisi look like?

Comment: @dragonx, question updated

Comment: Still looks ok... you might want to check that new.key is a valid key.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? You should first construct the keys and later use them in the model constructors

Comment: question's birthday.. I no longer use MapReduce..

Answer (score 2):

If you check the documentation for ndb models, you'll find that the ndb.Model constructor doesn't use the same syntax as the db.Model. To create an ancestor path for an ndb.Model use the keyword "key" and an ndb.Key with the ancestor path constructed. 
For example:

```
ekey= ndb.Key(pairs=[('kind1','id1')('kind2', 'id2')...('entity kind','entityid')])
a = Analisi(key=ekey,
        computo=cme.key,
        voce=new.key)
```